# Why doesn't it recognize join() as a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to capitalize every first letter of the given string, however every time I run the code I get the following error:

> TypeError: val[i].charAt(...).toUpperCase(...).join is not a function

```
function titleCase(str) {
var strArry = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
strArry.map(function (val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        return val[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase().join(' ') + strArry[i].splice(1);
    };
  });
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.protoype.toUpperCase()` returns a string, and `Array.prototype.join()` is on the Array prototype, not the string.

You probably want something like this...

```
return val[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val[i].slice(1);
```

...or possibly even better (at least shorter)...

```
function titleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(match) { return match.toUpperCase(); });
}
```

Here I am using a regex to match the first lowercase letter after a word boundary, and then using a custom replacer to return it uppercased.

If you supported more than latin, then use a Unicode range to select the characters.

Comment: @lettda You're not using the code suggested above (note that I didn't use `strArry`).

Comment: I was more so going for the first suggestion since it's close to what I already have as I'm not familiar with using regex

Answer (score 3):

[`toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) returns a `String` and `join` is not a method on that prototype.

If you run through your code and put a `typeof` check in before mucking with the string, you can see:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var strArry = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  strArry.map(function (val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
      var temp = val[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
      console.log(typeof temp);
      return temp;
    };
  });
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

You need to `join` the `Array` after you've mapped it to produce the final combined value.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this short piece of code which works well :

```
 var titleCase = (str) => str.split(" ").map(el => el[0].toUpperCase().concat(el.substr(1))).join(" ");
 console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with a bit a research and found that using val worked with me trying to use mpa()

```
function titleCase(str) {
  var strArry = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  var convert = strArry.map(function(val) {
    return val.replace(val.charAt(0), val.charAt(0).toUpperCase());
  });
  return convert.join(' ');
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Answer (score -1):

Im am not Familiar with Javascript, which is why I fo not know if it makes a difference between char and string.

I am quite sure you meant do an entirely different thing, namely return a string joined from capitalized letters. What you are (trying) to do here however is returning the result of your expression (val[i].andsoonandsoforth) after the first cycle of your for loop.

The reason why the expression doesn't work will be that join(string) is usually called on arrays of strings or characters. You are calling it on a single character however!

The solution would be to first split uf the string into characters, capitalize them, store them into an array, call join on that *array* and return the thing afterwards.

Or just use the likely existent builtin capitalize functions on strings.